# Getting the session cookie after login in a website

Tags: node.js, express, request, cheerio

I am trying to get the session cookie from a website after login. After looking some npm packages, I found that `request` package has an option where you can send username and password to login the website and get the token.
Here is my code:

```js
var rp = require('request-promise');
async parse_sign_up() {
  const options = {
    method: 'POST',
    uri: 'https://example/login/',
    form: {
      username: 'admin',
      password: 'admin'
    }
  };

  rp(options)
    .then(function(body) {
      console.log(body);

    })
    .catch(function(err) {
      console.log(err);
    });
}
```

The problem is that I get the session inside the error in console.
Also Since `request` pachage is depreceted, is there any alternative where I can use?

Here is the error:

```
statusCode: 302,
  error: '<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 3.2 Final//EN">\n' +
    '<title>Redirecting...</title>\n' +
    '<h1>Redirecting...</h1>\n' +
    '<p>You should be redirected automatically to target URL: <a href="/">/</a>. If not click the link.'
.
.
.
rawHeaders: [
      'Server',
      'nginx/1.18.0 (Ubuntu)',
      'Date',
      'Thu, 04 Aug 2022 13:44:51 GMT',
      'Content-Type',
      'text/html; charset=utf-8',
      'Content-Length',
      '208',
      'Location',
      'Connection',
      'close',
      'Vary',
      'Cookie',
      'Set-Cookie',
      'session=.eJwlzrsRwjAMANBdVKewLcmOsgyn70GbkIpjdwreBO8DjzrzesLxPu_c4PEKOMCEyhlJlqdaCx57zSFqtWdGdhlLqdC7JGdI2s5TBIdS69N5CSlhTKJeJhNjWd81WNmQmxBONs81aiqxy2gcuKpFZIq7ucMG95XnP9Ph-wPUmi_r.YuvNUw.kjUgJ39hP1Sfr0n9BNYs2EUAclc; HttpOnly; Path=/; SameSite=Lax'
    ],
```

Comment: A 302 response is not an error (even if the deprecated package seems to interpret it as one). You can alternatively use [`https.request`](https://nodejs.org/dist/latest-v16.x/docs/api/https.html#httpsrequesturl-options-callback).

Comment: Thank you Heiko, I dont think `http.request` has a form option where you can send username and password.

Comment: But you can use `https.request(url, {headers: {"Content-Type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"}, ...}).end("username=admin&password=admin")`.